# How to merge empty cells before "ok" with a for loop

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the problem with ms word table.
How to merge empty cells before "ok" with a for loop and then replace empty cell with text “waiting list”,
sample :

#before :

empty

empty

ok

empty

empty

empty

ok

empty

ok


 #After :

 waiting list

 ok

 waiting list

 ok

 waiting list

 ok

```
Sub try()
Dim i As Integer, x As Integer, k As Integer
x = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count
'k = empty cell count before "ok"

For i = 1 To x - 1
   With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
     If .Cell(i + 1, 1).Range.Text = Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
     .Cell(Row:=i, Column:=1).Merge MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=i + k, Column:=1)
     End If
   End With
Next i

For i = 1 To x - 1
   With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
     If .Cell(i, 1).Range.Text = Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
      .Cell(i, 1).Range.Text = “waiting list”         
    End If
   End With
Next i

End Sub
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know how it goes,

```
Sub try()
Dim i As Integer, x As Integer, k As Integer
x = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count
'k = empty cell count before "ok"
For i = 1 To x - 1
   With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
     If .Cell(i, 1).Range.Text = Chr(13) & Chr(7) And .Cell(i + 1, 1).Range.Text = Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
        On Error Resume Next
            .Cell(Row:=i, Column:=1).Merge MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=i + 1, Column:=1)
        On Error GoTo 0
        i = i - 1
        If i = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count - 1 Then
           GoTo EnterText
        End If
     End If
   End With
Next i

EnterText:
x = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count
For i = 1 To x
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
        If .Cell(i, 1).Range.Text = Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
          .Cell(i, 1).Range.Text = "waiting list"
        End If
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks , it works, but if I try to add 1 column "name", it's not work, I get error in 
 If .Cell(i, 1).Range.Text = Chr(13) & Chr(7) And .Cell(i + 1, 1).Range.Text = Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then

any idea?

Comment: you mean if you add header to the column you are getting the error?